# Is this linear mapping discontinuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $C[0,1]$ denote the vector space of all continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, endowed with the supremum norm, and let $D$ denote the subspace

$D:=\{x\in C[0,1]: x'' \text{ is continuous  and } x(0)=x'(0)=0 \}\subset C[0,1]$.

Is it true that the linear mapping $T: D\longrightarrow C[0,1]$, given by $Tx(t):=x''(t)+x(t)$, is continuous? And does there exist the inverse $T^{-1}$? If so, what is $T^{-1}$?

I think/guess that the mapping is not continuous. Any hint/comment will be appreciated.

Comment: For the first part consider the functions $\frac {x^{n}} n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, let $x_n(t)=t^n$. Then $x_n\in D$, and $Tx=n(n-1)t^{n-2}+t^n$. So $\|x_n\|=1$ for all $n$, while $\|Tx_n\|=n(n-1)+1$ (since $Tx_n$ is increasing). So 
$$
\frac{\|Tx_n\|}{\|x_n\|}=n(n-1)+1,
$$
and so $T$ is not bounded.

An inverse (as an unbounded operator) does exist: the initial value problem $$\tag1x''+x=f,\ x(0)=x'(0)=0$$ always has a unique solution if $f$ is continuous. So $T$ is onto. It is also one-to-one, because the homogeneous problem only has the solution $x=0$.

The linear map $T^{-1}$ maps $f$ to the solution $x$ of the IVP $(1)$. Since a fundamental set of solutions for the homogeneous problem in $(1)$ is given by $\cos t$, $\sin t$, one gets that 
$$
(T^{-1}f)(x)=\int_0^x(\cos t\sin x-\cos x\sin t)\,f(t)\,dt.
$$
The second part of your question was asked [earlier today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017778/how-do-i-show-a-linear-operator-is-bounded/3017920#3017920).